# How to Map keys in windows?

Tags: linux, windows

How do I map keys in windows?
I know how to do it in linux with xmodmap

```
xmodmap -e "keycode <value> = <letter>"
```

I know that windows has tools like sharpkeys, but is there a command in the powershell that allows me to do it myself? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator, aka [MSKLC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/keyboardlayouts.aspx).

Comment: that software has to do something... Basically I want to know how does that software maps the keys

Comment: MSKLC edits and generates a _keyboard layout_, which you can then install and activate as you install and activate any other keyboard layout. In Windows, a keyboard layout is a DLL, not a nice text configuration file. As far as I know there is no way to alter a keyboard layout dynamically -- there is no layer equivalent to `xkb`.